# Do corner kick takers get an assist for a scored goal?

Tags: football, statistics

Does the player who delivers a corner kick to the box get an assist if the ball is scored directly from the kick?

If not, how come they don't get an assist?

Comment: Maybe it could help to look at some examples. In the last [Liverpool-Man City mathch](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/matches/2013-2014/epl.match-report.html/liverpool-vs-man-city) Škrtel scored after a corner. Soccerway [shows an assist](http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2014/04/13/england/premier-league/liverpool-fc/manchester-city-football-club/1483790/?ICID=PL_MS_07) for Gerrard. But I did not find official assist statistics for this match on EPL website. Perhaps other users can find examples from other competitions, where we can see whether the kick taker was awarded an assist.

Comment: @Martin good idea, I was actually thinking this might be the best and easiest way to verify...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no specific rules for such statistics. In theory it may differ from league to league.

Even so, I've never seen any league do not counting pass from corner which leads to goal as a "goal assist". I can't find UEFA's official laws of statistics, but this is quote from [UEFA's fantasy football rules](http://en.uclfantasy.uefa.com/UEFA/15809/clienthowtoplay.do) and I'm sure this is a way which is used for official game statistics:

> A player will be credited with a 'goal assist' when he delivers/plays
>   the final pass, cross, header or shot, which leads to the goal being
>   scored. This will also apply to set plays (i.e. corner, free kick,
>   throw-in etc.)

Answer (score 4):

As with all statistics, the answer to that question will vary depending on who's counting. As far as I know, there are no "official guidelines" for football statistics, but I assume most statisticians do count assists from cornerkicks. Anything else would surprise me, but I can't really back it up with any real evidence...

Answer (score 1):

I know that on the [Barclays](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/players.html) premier league site there is a fantasy football game and they award points for an assist on corners and that is the official site for the Premier League. I always see this on sites like Goal.com as well where assists are awarded for corners.